# How to deal with non numerical categories in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R and have the following problem: I am working on a dataset that not only has numerical values, but also non numerical values (gender, state). I wanted to start to look through the data and find some correlations first. Well, this works only for numerical values obviously and the dataset doesnt find any correlations for the numerical values. I tried it out with ggcorr and it omits the non numerical columns.

My questions is: how do you treat such datasets? How do you find correlations if you have many non numerical values categories? Also what is the workflow on creating the lineal model for such a dataset? The model should predict if a person earns more or less then 50k a year.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: [This](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult) is the dataset which I am talking about. I was thinking about convert the categories into numerical values and then correlate through cor.test() but I am not sure if I would gain a valid correlation number this way. So basically my question is: how do I check the correlation between non-numerical and numerical data?

Comment: This question is extremely broad. Please try to be more specific in the things you want answered. Also, provide a minimum reproducible example. Thanks!

Comment: `pairs(iris)` will plot every pair of columns.

Comment: Generally for modeling factor variables are "one-hot" encoded, with a new column being created for each value of the factor and a binary value being placed in the column.  Most models in R will do this for you automatically.

Comment: Ok I edited the post. Thanks

Comment: Some of those variable are Likert scale (like education) and it might be appropriate to turn them into numbers and take a correlation coefficient.  But others it would not be, what occupation would get which number? What would it mean to one country higher?

Comment: @IanWesley right, education would make sense so it is kind of sortable (the higher the education the higher the number), but countries you cant sort.